# where to use aws x-ray patch all (python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

As documented, we can use `patch_all` to automatically create subsegments for aws services such as s3 and sqs. My question is where should I call this method.

For example, let's assume there are 2 files which use boto3 and we want to patch.
Because they are independent, we must call `patch_all` in both of them. Hence, we would have:

File `a.py`:

```py
import boto3
from xray_recorder import patch_all
patch_all()
```

File `b.py`:

```py
import boto3
from xray_recorder import patch_all
patch_all()
```

Now, lets assume we have a module named `c.py` which import both `a.py` and `b.py`:

```py
import a
import b
```

In this flow, `boto3` would be patched twice.

The only solution I found for it is to import `boto3` only from inside a file, named for example `my_boto3.py` which imports `boto3` and patch it.

What is the good practice to patch `boto3`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `patch_all()` in the main function. Just follow instructions [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/7ddbfbd0d12731664cc9bb6e1067b0a0c765d025/docs/thirdparty.rst#patching-supported-libraries), and it should work for all of the libraries([functions and classes](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/88406fdbdba349ac42af71106e5b07c2ad58a2d0/aws_xray_sdk/core/patcher.py#L139)) patched within the same application.

Comment: what is the "main" function when working with lambdas? there is no main

Comment: That would be the lambda handler or, better yet, do it outside any function. It will save time in case the lambda context is reused. You may also want to check lambda power tools: https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-python/2.8.0/